# CURL error "URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL" when trying to pass variable as a part of URL

Tags: bash, curl, jq

When I'm trying to execute script below and getting error: "curl: (3) URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL"

```
#!/bin/bash

stage="develop"
branch="branch_name"

getDefinition=$(curl -u user@example.com:password -X GET "https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_apis/build/definitions?api-version=5.1")

for def in $(echo "$getDefinition" | jq '.value[] | select (.path=="\\Some_path\\'$stage'") | .id'); do
  getBuildInfo=$(curl -u user@example.com:password -X GET "https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_apis/build/definitions/${def}\?api-version=5.1")
        # echo $def
        body=$(echo "${getBuildInfo}" | jq '.repository.defaultBranch = "refs/heads/release/'"${branch}"'"' | jq '.options[].inputs.branchFilters = "[\"+refs/heads/release/'"${branch}"'\"]"' | jq '.triggers[].branchFilters[] = "+refs/heads/release/'"${branch}"'"')
        echo ${body} > data.json    
done
```

It happens when I'm trying to pass variable **${def}** into a line:

```
curl -u user@example.com:password -X GET "https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_apis/build/definitions/${def}\?api-version=5.1"
```

But when I declare an array, curl works as expected.
Example:

```
declare -a def
def=(1 2 3 4)

curl -u user@example.com:password -X GET "https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_apis/build/definitions/${def}\?api-version=5.1"
```

Could you please suggest how can I pass variable into URL properly?

Comment: Try to echo "-"$def"-" to see if there are unwanted leading or ending characters

Comment: That may not show nonprinting characters, and `echo` might mistake the "-" for an option delimiter. I'd recommend `echo "'$def'" | LC_ALL=C cat -vt` instead. Or use `set -x` before the problem section, so the shell will print the commands as it executed them (probably with weird quoting/escaping around any funny characters).

Comment: Thanks a lot @franzisk, @GordonDavisson!
Variable **$def** contained ^M character. After removing this CURL works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Set `IFS=$' \t\r\n'` at the top of your script.

`IFS` is the Interactive Field Separator.

In UNIX, `IFS` is space, tab, newline, or `$' \t\n'`, but on Windows this needs to be `$' \t\r\n'`.

The ^M character is `\r`.

Comment: it works, thank you! I tried `cURL`ing a remote server, but it kept spewing out this error message. So why this issue happens in the first place? Is that because I am using a unix shell on my machine and the remote server, supposedly, uses windows??? Is that one of those unicorn servers that run windows?

Comment: When bash is scarfing text input with the UNIX field separator on a Windows machine, it doesn't swallow the carriage return (\r) when splitting strings, so the ^M character gets stuck on all strings that bash is passing around.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to call curl for 4 times? If so.

```
for def in 1 2 3 4; do curl -u user@example.com:password -X GET "https://dev.azure.com/organization/project/_apis/build/definitions/${def}\?api-version=5.1"; done
```

Comment: Issue already solved. Variable contained ^M character. After removing this CURL works fine.